# Kinect Audio with Kinect SDK and C++

Tags: c++, audio, kinect, directshow, kinect-sdk

I'm getting linker errors when trying to use Kinect Audio Data using C++.

I looked at the [programmers guide here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj883681.aspx).

But it does not provide any details as to which header files to include or which libraries to compile the code with.

I included the following headers -

```
#include <Dmo.h>
#include <Wmcodecdsp.h>
#include <uuids.h>
#include <propsys.h>
```

Now I get a linker error saying -

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _FORMAT_WaveFormatEx
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MEDIASUBTYPE_PCM
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _MEDIATYPE_Audio
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _MoInitMediaType@8 referenced in function _main
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IMediaObject
```

What should I link my project with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve linker issues you throw `.lib`s in:

- `strmiids.lib` - generic DirectShow symbols
- `dmoguids.lib`, `msdmo.lib` - DMO related
- `wmcodecdspuuid.lib` - Vista+ DMO/DSP related

C++ code:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "strmiids.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "dmoguids.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "msdmo.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "wmcodecdspuuid.lib")
```

Comment: Wow! That solved the first 4 errors. Thank you!
Which `.lib`s should I use for `unresolved external symbol _IID_IMediaObject'?
Thank you!